# How to make dynamic initial url on webview

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Here is my code... I need to make initial URL dynamic so that I can use it for many times. how to make classes parameterized? so that I can call it like a function? I'm trying to make it reusable.Is there any way how to make it optional or parameterized?

```
  class defaultWebpage extends StatefulWidget {
  const defaultWebpage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<defaultWebpage> createState() => _defaultWebpageState();
}

class _defaultWebpageState extends State<defaultWebpage> {
  int position = 1;
  @override
  WebViewController? controller;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (await controller!.canGoBack()) {
          controller?.goBack();
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      },
      child: IndexedStack(
        index: position,
        children: [
          WebView(
              initialUrl: "https://stackoverflow.com/",
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onPageStarted: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  position = 1;
                });
              },
              onPageFinished: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  position = 0;

                  controller?.evaluateJavascript(
                      "document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-wrapper')[0].style.display='none'");

                  controller?.evaluateJavascript(
                      "document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0].style.display='none'");
                });
              },
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                this.controller = controller;
              }),
          Container(
            child: Center(
              child: shimmer_effect(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
defaultWebpage(url:yourDynamicUrl)
```

```
class defaultWebpage extends StatefulWidget {
  defaultWebpage({Key? key,required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  String url;
  @override
  State<defaultWebpage> createState() => _defaultWebpageState();
}

class _defaultWebpageState extends State<defaultWebpage> {
  int position = 1;
  @override
  WebViewController? controller;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (await controller!.canGoBack()) {
          controller?.goBack();
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      },
      child: IndexedStack(
        index: position,
        children: [
          WebView(
              initialUrl: widget.url,
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onPageStarted: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  position = 1;
                });
              },
              onPageFinished: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  position = 0;

                  controller?.evaluateJavascript(
                      "document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-wrapper')[0].style.display='none'");

                  controller?.evaluateJavascript(
                      "document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0].style.display='none'");
                });
              },
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                this.controller = controller;
              }),
          Container(
            child: Center(
              child: shimmer_effect(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...but another exception occurred : throw UnsupportedError(
              "Trying to use the default webview implementation for $defaultTargetPlatform but there isn't a default one");
      }

Comment: i don't understand your error :/

Comment: solved bro... this error was occurred for running on web... too much thanks to you ❤

Comment: hey bro... can you tell me why webpage is loading too slowly for using this class ... normally its loading too fast

Comment: i don't know bro :/ sorry